# matplotlib widget in QtDesigner4

Tags: python, qt4, matplotlib, pyqt4

I would like to create a "custom widget" in QtDesigner4 for matplotlib widgets.

I'm familiar with getting matplotlib widgets in QtDesigner3, and I have little problem manually coding the widget in Qt4. I'm not entirely sure how to do this the new way that QtDesigner handles custom widgets.

There appears to be [some documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html), but I thought I'd ask if someone else has coded a solution before I attempt to do so myself.

Comment: See an example of a [plugin](https://github.com/warvariuc/wic/blob/master/wic/widgets/designer_plugin.py) for qt designer and [starting](https://github.com/warvariuc/wic/blob/master/qt_designer.pyw) the designer in a way that it sees custom widgets. It works for me using Python3, Linux